# Elastic Search: matching documents whose array contains this field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document similar to this:

```
{
name: "bob",
contains: ["a", "b", "c"]
},
{
name: "mary",
contains: ["a", "b"]
},
{
name: "Jason",
contains: ["b"]
}
```

I want to make a query to find all of the people who contain "a" (bob and mary). How can I write the query?

EDIT:

Current query:

```
                query: {
                bool: {
                    must: [
                        { match: { exists: "yes" }},
                        { term: {contains: "a"}}
                    ],
                    must_not: [
                        { match: { status: "removed"}}
                    ]

                }
            }
```

Comment: Find an answer to this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A term filter/query on the `contains` field, such as `{term: {contains: "a"}}` will get you what you need. Assuming that you want to just match any document which satisfies that criteria, the full query would look something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "contains": "a"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works because arrays of values are indexed individually, and a term query will find documents which contain an array containing that value if the field queried is a list.

Comment: I added the {term: {contains: "a"}} bit into a normal query I had. Hope that helps!

Comment: Still does nothing for me. I must be doing something wrong.