# Elasticsearch: Matching documents with an array in it

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm very new to elasticsearch and the documentation really just confuses me so please bear with me a little bit here.

I have an index called `zproducts` and under it a type called `item` which is mapped looks somewhat like this:

```
{
   "item_name" : "Product A",
   "category_ids" : [ "id1", "id2" ]
},
{
   "item_name" : "Product B",
   "category_ids" : [ "id1" ]
},
{
   "item_name" : "Product C",
   "category_ids" : [ "id2" ]
}
```

I want to be able to query for items that match at least one of the of the categories. ie. querying for `id2` will return products A and C.

It would seem that I have the exact same problem that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228375/elastic-search-matching-documents-whose-array-contains-this-field) guy had.

But the solution suggested there just doesn't work for me.

This is my current query:

`/zproducts/items/_search`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "category_ids": "id2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Subsequent test query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "category_ids": "id2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both queries return ALL the items on store and not just the ones I'm trying to query for.

There was also the original query which, for some reason, used to work but stopped working altogether.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "category_ids": {
                            "query": "id2",
                            "operator": "or"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Can anyone please shed some light?

Comment: All your queries should give you the expected results if type of `category_ids` is `string`. I just tried them on my local setup. Can you share the result of `GET zproducts/item/_mapping`?

Comment: @baskar- let me put it in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/K9bv6vNp) as it's pretty long. I'm pretty sure `category_ids` is of type `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "category_ids": "id2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is correct. Make sure you are making your request as `POST /zproducts/items/_search`, rather than `GET /zproducts/items/_search` - getting all documents in an index back for a query is a good hint that the query body is being ignored, which is a good hint that you're using GET; many clients will not send a request body with a GET request, which ES interprets as a blank query.

Comment: Almost fell of my chair there from the facepalm. I've been using `GET` all along, I did not realize you needed to use `POST` for queries. But now I get a different issue, using this query with `POST` returns an empty set.

Comment: Try broadening the query until it starts returning results, then trim it down. You may also try just `POST/zproducts/_search` if you only have the one document type in there.

Comment: Funnily enough, the query didn't work but the original one (see last query on the question) started to work again. I think I'm about an inch away from going insane. Thank you for the help, though, and that pointer about the `GET` vs `POST` thing. Hope this helps someone else.